# Userform Store Row Information Found to Update Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a userform that I want to find information to populate textboxes if two criteria are found within the same row. The code works find with CommandButton1, but I want to be able to update the textboxes of information found with CommandButton2, so I need the row stored and able to change that row's information with CommandButton2_Click(). I would also like a way to slightly recode CommandButton1_Click() to be able to match only part of txtsearch and txtname instead of looking at the whole value.

Also, I get an error with CommandButton2_Click() that I have a run-time error '1004': application-defined or object-defined error for `Cells(currentrow, 5).Value = aa`. This is the portion where I want the information on the original page to be updated with the changed information the user typed. Any help is appreciated.

I've already made a couple edits but can someone please tell me how to change my code more than this to make it work? Or address the looking for part of the value instead of just the whole value?

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim ws As Worksheet, cel As Range
    Set ws = Sheets("The Goods")
    For Each cel In ws.Cells(2, 2).Resize(ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row).Cells
        If cel.Value = Me.txtname.Value And cel.Offset(, 2).Value = Me.txtsearch.Value Then
            currentrow = cel.Row
            Me.txt1.Value = cel.Offset(, 3).Value & currentrow
            Me.txt2.Value = cel.Offset(, 1).Value
            Me.txt3.Value = cel.Offset(, 4).Value
            Me.txt4.Value = cel.Offset(, 5).Value
            Me.txt5.Value = cel.Offset(, 6).Value
            Me.txt6.Value = cel.Offset(, 7).Value
            Me.txt7.Value = cel.Offset(, 8).Value
            Me.txt8.Value = cel.Offset(, 9).Value
            Me.txt9.Value = cel.Offset(, 10).Value
            Me.txt10.Value = cel.Offset(, 11).Value
            Me.txt11.Value = cel.Offset(, 12).Value
        End If
    Next cel

End Sub

Public Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim aa As String, bb As String, cc As String, dd As String, ee As String, ff As String, gg As String, hh As String, ii As String, jj As String, kk As String

aa = txt1.Value
Cells(currentrow, 5).Value = aa
bb = txt2.Value
Cells(currentrow, 3).Value = bb
cc = txt3.Value
Cells(currentrow, 6).Value = cc
dd = txt4.Value
Cells(currentrow, 7).Value = dd
ee = txt5.Value
Cells(currentrow, 8).Value = ee
ff = txt6.Value
Cells(currentrow, 9).Value = ff
gg = txt7.Value
Cells(currentrow, 10).Value = gg
hh = txt8.Value
Cells(currentrow, 11).Value = hh
ii = txt9.Value
Cells(currentrow, 12).Value = ii
jj = txt10.Value
Cells(currentrow, 13).Value = jj
kk = txt11.Value
Cells(currentrow, 14).Value = kk
End Sub
```

Comment: Add `Option Explicit` to the top of the module. Where is `currentRow` declared?

Comment: Ok and 'currentrow = cel.Row` line 6 @BigBen

Comment: Yes, but where is `currentRow` *declared* (`Dim`, `Public`...)?

Comment: When I add `Dim currentrow As Integer` to each sub, I still get the run-time error 1004 for the same row. @BigBen

Comment: Right - because `currentRow` is `0`. Maybe give [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/understanding-scope-and-visibility) about scope a read.

Comment: After changing both subs to Public, I am getting "compile error: variable not defined" for the same row. @BigBen

Comment: You have a bunch of issues that raise questions: in `CommandButton1_Click` there is no indication of where the value of `rFound` is set, also you're looping over (possibly many) rows that match your `If` statement, but only the values from the last row will show up in the textboxes. In `CommandButton2_Click`, as @BigBen pointed out, `currentRow` is never set to any value, plus by using `Cells(currentRow, ...)` you are referring to the currently active worksheet and maybe not the sheet you intend.

Comment: Oops, `rFound` was supposed to be `cel.Value`. I'm just confused as to how to make `commandbutton2_click` reference the row that was found from the first sub.  @PeterT

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick, non-working example to help you understand how to code around your problem. Global variables are not always the solution, especially in `Public` modules. But you are working in a user form `Class`.

You can establish a set of private variable that are available to all of your methods in your userform class. I've used a [technique discussed on Rubberduck](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2018/04/25/private-this-as-tsomething/) to create an internal variable named `this`. It has helped me keep my variables organized within a class. Notice that I'm initializing the `Worksheet` variable when the userform is created.

Inside your button click methods, you capture the data (such as a row number) and use it as needed.

But please always use `Option Explicit` and create names for your variables that are meaningful :)

```
Option Explicit

Private Type InternalData
    matchedRow As Long
    theGoodsWS As Worksheet
End Type
Private this As InternalData

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim searchRange As Range
    Dim cel As Range

    With this.theGoodsWS
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        Set searchRange = .Cells(2, 2).Resize(lastRow)
        this.matchedRow = -1
        For Each cel In searchRange.Cells
            If (cel.Value = Me.txtname.Value) And _
               (cel.Offset(0, 2).Value = Me.textsearch.Value) Then
                this.matchedRow = cel.Row
                '--- assign your textbox values here
            End If
        Next cel
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    If this.matchedRow <> -1 Then
        With this.theGoodsWS
            .Cells(this.matchedRow, 5).Value = Me.txt1.Value
            '...
        End With
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Set this.theGoodsWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("The Goods")
    this.matchedRow = -1
End Sub
```

Comment: I like the idea on this, but the line `.Cells(this.matchedRow, 5).Value = Me.txt1.Value` gives me an error so it's still not matching the last sub matchedRow to the next sub

Comment: Also, I would really like a way that this task can be accomplished but only by typing in part of the value for txtname or txtsearch, if you know a way to change it for that. Like to add `LookAt:=xlPart`

Comment: @Tara - I added some code to the example above to show how `this.matchedRow` is set to `-1` to indicate an invalid value. This would be the case when no matches in any rows are found. This way, if you click `CommandButton2` before `CommandButton1`, or if no matches were found, then you shouldn't get an error. If you're still getting an error then your problem has something to do with getting the value out of `Me.txt1.Value`. We would have to know more about how everything is defined to clear that up.

Comment: Your second question to change the way a user searches for the value may generate more help on this site if you show more code in what you've tried and then ask a separate question. Good luck!